# Retrieving files on Parse - Images

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have already managed to store image files into parse. My question lies in retrieving it. In the sense that in the registration process users are asked to upload a profile picture, and where the image is later stored into parse as an image. My issue lies in retrieving it, where along with pulling information like name, headline, age for a potential match, I also want to be able to retrieve the picture.

Below is the code, where I retrieve string information, but where I would want to retrieve files as well.

```
public class MatchingActivity extends Activity {

 private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");


    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.matching);

        logoutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logoutButton);
        logoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        setConversationsList();
    }
    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
      // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

           ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

         //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

           query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
           // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
           // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
           query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
           query.setLimit(1);
           query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
           query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Minimum_Age", minimumAge).whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
           query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Maximum_Age", maximumAge).whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", userage);
  //  query.whereWithinKilometers("Maximum_Distance", point, maxDistance)





        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());

                 //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                    }




                    usersListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersListView);
                    namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                            R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                            openConversation(names, i);
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
           public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null) {
                   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                   startActivity(intent);
               } else {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                       "Error finding that user",
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
           }
        });
    }
}
```

If you have any question, if like it.

**Update**
Image code

```
ParseFile image = (ParseFile) userData.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");

                        //call the function 

                        displayImage(image, image_expert);
                        //and here is the function

                            private void displayImage(ParseFile thumbnail, final ImageView img) {

                                if (thumbnail != null) {
                                    thumbnail.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                                            if (e == null) {
                                                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                                        data.length);

                                                if (bmp != null) {

                                                    Log.e("parse file ok", " null");
                                                    img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                                                    (display.getWidth() / 5),
                                                    (display.getWidth() /50), false));
                                                    img.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, 10));
                                                    img.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);



                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                Log.e("paser after downloade", " null");
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {

                                    Log.e("parse file", " null");

                                    // img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                                    img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                                }

                            }
                            names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                            names.add(userList.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());


                        //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                    }
```

activity code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);


        return view;
    }

private void setConversationsList() {
    currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
    names = new ArrayList<String>();
    // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

    //  query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

    query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId());
    // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
    // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
    query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
    //query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
    //query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
    query.orderByDescending("Name");




    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

        public void done(List<ParseUser> userList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (int i=0; i<userList.size(); i++) {
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    names.add(userList.get(i).get("Headline").toString());

                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) userData.getParseFile("ProfilePicture");

                    //call the function 

                    displayImage(image, image_expert);
                    //and here is the function

                        private void displayImage(ParseFile thumbnail, final ImageView img) {

                            if (thumbnail != null) {
                                thumbnail.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {

                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0,
                                                    data.length);

                                            if (bmp != null) {

                                                Log.e("parse file ok", " null");
                                                img.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,
                                                (display.getWidth() / 5),
                                                (display.getWidth() /50), false));
                                                img.setImageBitmap(getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, 10));
                                                img.setPadding(10, 10, 0, 0);



                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            Log.e("paser after downloade", " null");
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            } else {

                                Log.e("parse file", " null");

                                // img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                                img.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                            }

                        }
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("Age").toString());
                        names.add(userList.get(i).get("ActivityName").toString());


                    //       names.add(userList.get(i).getParseObject("ProfilePicture").;


                }




                usersListView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistview);
                namesArrayAdapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                R.layout.user_list_item, names);
                usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                usersListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                        openConversation(names, i);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error loading user list",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
        public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error finding that user",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Issues on the following line

```
                private void displayImage(ParseFile thumbnail, final ImageView img) {
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error on token ",", ; 
     expected
    - Syntax error on token "(", ; 
     expected
    - Syntax error on token ")", ; 
     expected
```

Comment: have you tried ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getBytes(String key)?

Comment: Thanks for your response, and suggestion. I haven't tried yet, however, it would not be selecting the image of the current user but of each user that would be populated. In parse the column is identified as a file and not a string, which is why I cant just retrieve the string.

Answer (score 1):

see if something like below would help:

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    currentUser.fetchInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                ParseFile file = (ParseFile)object.get("image");
                if(file != null){
                    file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                        public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                                if(bitmap != null){
                                    imageAccount.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                }else{
                                    Log.d(TAG, "file null?");
                                }
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "ParseFile ParseException: " + e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "ParseFile is null");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ParseException: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion. I have notice that this code is referring to the current user. It would actually retrieve the profile picture of each individual in the list. For example, the current retrieves the name, the headline and the age of the user.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion and with support tried to achieve something similar. I have updated my post under the update section of my initial post. If you could look into it that would be greatly helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you store a pointer to type 'file' in parse, u get a URL and a name .

Anytime you have reference to the file, you should be able to also get the URL.

Use the URL to do an async get and to generate a local bitmap for using the photo in a view.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have update my post under the update section of my initial post. I am just experiencing some issues implementing it. If you assist in anyway that would be greatful